# Why won't C++ allow this default value?

Tags: c++, templates, gcc

Why won't GCC allow a default parameter here?

```
 template<class edgeDecor, class vertexDecor, bool dir>
 Graph<edgeDecor,int,dir> Graph<edgeDecor,vertexDecor,dir>::Dijkstra(vertex s, bool print = false) const
 {
```

This is the output I get:

```
graph.h:82: error: default argument given for parameter 2 of ‘Graph<edgeDecor, int, dir> Graph<edgeDecor, vertexDecor, dir>::Dijkstra(Vertex<edgeDecor, vertexDecor, dir>, bool)’
graph.h:36: error: after previous specification in ‘Graph<edgeDecor, int, dir> Graph<edgeDecor, vertexDecor, dir>::Dijkstra(Vertex<edgeDecor, vertexDecor, dir>, bool)’
```

Can anyone see why I'm getting this?

Comment: I can't see why you're getting this, because you're only including part of the relevant code.  Your errors refer to both lines 36 and 82, so you need to include both in the question.

Comment: Sorry Brooks, good point. Line 36 was the function prototype in my class.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You seem to already have declared the function (including the default parameter) in `graph.h`, line 36. Don't repeat the default value in the function implementation, specifying it one time in the declaration is enough.

Answer (score 2):

You've specified one of the template parameters:

```
Graph<edgeDecor,int,dir> Graph<edgeDecor,vertexDecor,dir>::
                ^^^
```

Change it to match:

```
Graph<edgeDecor,vertexDecor,dir> Graph<edgeDecor,vertexDecor,dir>::
```

Comment: This does not seem to be a problem, after following sth's advice that error disappeared.

Answer (score 2):

default arguments must be given only in the declaration of your method, not the definition